# .Net Core - Consuming web service via web references which uses .net framework

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am planning to build a webapi(serviceapi) in .net core which should call other(clientWCF) service to get the information. other service(clientWCF) is a WCF service which uses .net framework. 
What would be the right way to consume the service in .net core, using web reference or service reference?
if we use web reference/service reference, does the executing environment needs .net framework? if so, wouldn't it defeat the purpose of building the webapi with .net core.
Please provide your thoughts!

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/70

Answer (score 0):

> If we use web reference/service reference, does the executing environment needs .net framework?

No.

You can find all the details of consuming WCF services using .net core here: https://github.com/dotnet/wcf

There's no requirement to use the .net framework to consume WCF services just because they happen to be implemented using it, however, you should probably read this page to check all the features you want are currently implemented:

https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/master/release-notes/SupportedFeatures-v2.1.0.md

If you're targeting 2.1, the support is very good.